Android BLE Advertisement flags: How to change
Attached is an image of two phones running nRFConnect, left is scanning, and right is advertising
On the scanner, we always see flags with Classic and LE, instead of LE only.
I have same result in advertiser app I implemented.
Is there any way in Android to change this flag to LE only (in my app)? I did not find any API for this purpose.


No, you can't force ad flags to show "LE only" on Android using the standard Bluetooth APIs. These flags are controlled by the Bluetooth stack itself and you cannot change them through the Android API.

Thanks for the response. Are you aware of any documentation or code reference to support this?
